# asp.net GridView replace Checkboxes with Yes/No in Dynamic GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, boolean, checkbox

I have a gridview that displays the results of a custom query.  The number of columns is unknown, and whether or not the DataTable being bound contains boolean columns is unknown.  The title of columns that will contain a boolean value is also unknown.

Without knowing that information beforehand, is there a way to be able to replace the checkboxes with a simple Yes/No ?

This seems quite straightforward with predefined columns, but not so much in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution not long after I posted the question.  What I ended up doing is:

- Create a clone the DataTable with each column of type string,
- Iterate through each item array (object[]) to search for "True" and "False" and replace with "Yes" and "No", respectively,
- Create a new DataRow, set its ItemArray property to the new object array, and add the new DataRow to the new DataTable.

Here is the code of how it was done:

```
        DataTable Clone = ResultsTable.Clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < Clone.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            Clone.Columns[i].DataType = typeof(string);
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in ResultsTable.Rows)
        {
            DataRow r = null;
            object[] ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
            for (int i = 0; i< ItemArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ItemArray[i].ToString() == "True")   ItemArray[i] = "Yes";
                if (ItemArray[i].ToString() == "False")  ItemArray[i] = "No";
            }

            r = Clone.NewRow();
            r.ItemArray = ItemArray;
            Clone.Rows.Add(r);
        }
```

This concept should be applicable to similar DataTable textual transformations as well.